# JSON in jsp file only accepts return values from my MVC controller that are null.

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring, controller

My JSP file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function suggest() {

     $.getJSON("/practice-webapp/getOrgList.htm", 
        { searchee: $("#searchee").val() }, 
          function(data) { alert(data); });

    }

    </script>

Search Org Name: <input id="searchee" onkeyup="suggest()" />
```

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getOrgList.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getOrgList(@RequestParam String searchee) {

        System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + searchee );
        return searchee;
    }
```

Whenever I enter a string in the search field, the "alert(data)" is not executed. However, if I use backspace until the field is empty, the "alert(data)" is executed, but obviously it contains a null value. I am just testing the json capability. All I want is to display the string returned by my controller.
(By the way, the searchee value is indeed received by the controller.)

Comment: By the way, I used the following libs:

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom/js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/json.min.js"></script>

I'm sure that the path are correct.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a string from getOrgList action where as getJSON expects a well formed json string because of which you are not seeing anything in the response. Try to send the below

```
 public @ResponseBody String getOrgList(@RequestParam String searchee) {

        System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + searchee );
        return "{ 'searchee': '"+searchee+"' }";
    }
```

Comment: should have been using some json lib

Comment: @ShankarSangoli I tried your suggestion, now it prints nothing at all.

Comment: @gplus - What are you looking for? Try to alert "data.searchee" in alert, you should see what you type in the textbox.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli still nothing. :(

Comment: Are you sure the action is hittne properly and its getting the input that you send? Can you put a debug point and see?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Whenever I type, I always see the line executed: System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + searchee );

Comment: what you see in searchee string when you inspect it?

Comment: @ShankarSangoli The line: System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + searchee ); --- Shows exactly what I typed in the search box.

Comment: I NOW UNDERSTAND why it wouldn't display the string. It's because can receive any object type (Integer, Character), just not a String object. Yey!

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Yep. I finally figured it out. But now I have another problem (a more advanced one... hehe). Anyway, thanks for the effort in replying to my question.